# Implementing map function

Tags: java, oop, functional-programming

I am creating a 'SpecialList' and am require to implement the map function. The list should be lazy, and will only produce values when evaluated.

toString() returns "?" if the value is not yet available; returns the string representation of the value otherwise.

get() called when the contents is needed. If the value is already available, return that value; otherwise, compute the value and return it. The computation should only be done once for the same value.

Here's what I have:

```
public <U> SpecialList<U> map(Function<T, U> mapper) {
    if (!this.isAvailable) {
        return new SpecialList<U>(this.supplier);
    }
    return new SpecialList<U>(mapper, value);
}

// private constructor
private SpecialList(CachedSupplier<T> s) {
    this.supplier = s;
    this.isAvailable = false;
}
```

However, it is telling me that there's no valid constuctor because T cannot be converted to U.

```
SpecialList.java:65: error: no suitable constructor found for SpecialList(SpecialList<T>.CachedSupplier<T>)
            return new SpecialList<U>(this.supplier);
                   ^
    constructor SpecialList.SpecialList(U) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; SpecialList<T>.CachedSupplier<T> cannot be converted to U)
    constructor SpecialList.SpecialList(Supplier<U>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; SpecialList<T>.CachedSupplier<T> cannot be converted to Supplier<U>)
```

Doesn't the 'U' become a T when returned?

How do I go about solving this? I am still a little unclear about the method level generic types. But I was told that I need to add the < U > for my map method.

Below is my code in full:

```
class SpecialList<T> {
    class CachedSupplier<T> {
        private Supplier<? extends T> supplier;
        private T value;
        boolean isAvailable;

        public CachedSupplier(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
            this.supplier = supplier;
        }

        public T get() {
            if (!isAvailable) {
                value = supplier.get();
                isAvailable = true;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    private CachedSupplier<T> supplier;
    private T value;
    boolean isAvailable;

    private SpecialList(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.isAvailable = true;
    }

    private SpecialList(Supplier<T> s) {
        this.supplier = new CachedSupplier<T>(s);
        this.isAvailable = false;
    }

    private SpecialList(CachedSupplier<T> s) {
        this.supplier = s;
        this.isAvailable = false;
    }

    private <R> SpecialList(Function<T, R> mapper, T v) {
        this.supplier = new CachedSupplier<T>(() -> mapper.apply(v));
        this.isAvailable = false;
    }

    public static <T> SpecialList<T> of(T value) {
        return new SpecialList<>(value);
    }

    public static <T> SpecialList<T> of(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return new SpecialList<>(supplier);
    }

    public <R> SpecialList<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper) {
        if (!this.isAvailable) {
            return new SpecialList<>(this.supplier);
        }
        return new SpecialList<R>(mapper, value);
    }

    public T get() {
        if(this.isAvailable) {
            return this.value;
        } else {
            this.value = this.supplier.get();
            this.isAvailable = true;
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am still a little confused with Generic Types etc. so please let me know if there's anything odd/I can improve!

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you provided more code.  Like your basic `SpecialList` class.  And `CachedSupplier`.

Comment: done! sorry for missing those out!

Comment: “*Doesn't the 'U' become a T when returned?*” Of course not. Why should the `T` become a `U`? These are different types. The argument `Function<T, U> mapper` tells how you can convert a `T` to an `U`, which will happen when you apply that function. But your `new SpecialList<U>(this.supplier)` expression doesn’t use the mapper at all. Your `CachedSupplier<T>` provides a `T`, not a `U`. You could create a new `Supplier` that applies the mapper function, e.g. `new SpecialList<U>(() -> mapper.apply( this.supplier.get()))`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you posted, there is a compile-time error in one of the constructors for class `SpecialList`...

```java
private <R> SpecialList(Function<T, R> mapper, T v) {
    this.supplier = new CachedSupplier<T>(() -> mapper.apply(v));
    this.isAvailable = false;
}
```

Firstly, in the code you posted, there is no constructor in inner class `CachedSupplier` that takes a `Function` parameter, so you need to add one with this signature:

```java
public <R> CachedSupplier(Function<T, R> mapper)
```

And the second problem with the `SpecialList` constructor is the lambda expression. Abstract method `apply` in interface `Function` has a parameter, which your lambda expression is missing. So the constructor code should be:

```java
private <R> SpecialList(Function<T, R> mapper, T v) {
    this.supplier = new CachedSupplier<T>((v) -> mapper.apply(v));
    this.isAvailable = false;
}
```

Comment: In your last statement, you can't redefine `v` in the constructor.

Comment: @Abra the "second problem" wasn't there initially. His CachedSupplier-constructors take Supplier as argument and therefore a lambda expression of the kind 
() -> mapper.apply(v) was perfectly fine. Just his mapper and value in the argument had the wrong type <T, R> and T instead of <R, T> and R

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing an overkill by checking `isAvailable` in both, the `SpecialList` and the `CachedSupplier`. It seems enough to me to do so in the `CachedSupplier` and reduce the members of `SpecialList` to just the `supplier` (which is, when the value is available, simply a value-getter without additional costly evaluations). And in the constructors you make sure that the `supplier` is a cached one, when needed (i.e. when you don't have the value yet).
So here's my suggestion. Further comments are directly in the source code (which compiles now without errors or warnings):

```
class SpecialList<T> {
static class CachedSupplier<R> implements Supplier<R> {
    /* R is a priori an idependent parameter. If you call it T again, then you get a warning
     * that the original T is hidden within the new nested class (though it wouldn't really matter here),
     * as one doesn't need to refer to it. I made it static, as you don't need an instance to define it. */
    private Supplier<? extends R> supplier;
    private R value;
    boolean isAvailable;

    public CachedSupplier(Supplier<? extends R> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.isAvailable = false;
    }

    @Override
    public R get() {
        if (!isAvailable) {
            value = supplier.get();
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return value;
    }
}

private Supplier<T> supplier;

private SpecialList(T value) {
    /* in this case no lazy evaluation and no caching needed */
    this.supplier = () -> value;
}

private SpecialList(Supplier<T> s) {
    this.supplier = new CachedSupplier<T>(s);
}

private SpecialList(CachedSupplier<T> s) {
    this.supplier = s;
}

private <R> SpecialList(Function<R, T> mapper, R v) {
    /* This constructor is not needed anymore in my suggested code. 
     * I left it simply, in order to show how to fix the type errors related to it. 
     * if I understood correctly the intentions of this constructor,
     * R and T have to be swapped w.r.t the original post.
     * This is a constructor that uses an R-value and a mapper R->T to create a SpecialList<T> */
    this.supplier = new CachedSupplier<T>(() -> mapper.apply(v));
}

public static <T> SpecialList<T> of(T value) {
    return new SpecialList<>(value);
}

public static <T> SpecialList<T> of(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return new SpecialList<>(supplier);
}

public <R> SpecialList<R> map(Function<T, R> mapper) {
    /* mapper is here different (opposite direction) than in the last of the constructors.
     * Here we have an existing SpecialList containing a value of Type T which will be turned into a
     * SpecialList containing a value of type R by applying a mapper T->R after getting the value from
     * the original SpecialList */

    return new SpecialList<R>(() -> mapper.apply(get()));
}

public T get() {

    return this.supplier.get();
}
}
```

This solution doesn't yet take care of the `toString()` implementation. When you want to implement also the latter, it might be more natural to make `SpecialList` a subclass of `CachedSupplier` (with the additional map- and toString- methods and direct access to `isAvailable`)

Comment: Note that, although not needed anymore, in the method `map()` you could now (just from type point of view) return  the constructor `new SpecialList<R>(mapper, get())` without type errors. It is a bit confusing that the constructor has seemingly a mapper with the opposite direction, but in the `map()` the target type is not `T`anymore but `R` and you put a value of type `T` as argument (which automatically chooses the type Parameter `<R>` of the constructor to be `T`). This is why they get swapped and then everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your map function is changing the SpecialList type parameter from T to R. But in the fragment highlited by compiler you return still SpecialList.

Things you can do:

1. If you are not planning to change the type of elements with your map() function, get rid of R, and replace `Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper` with `Function<? super T,? extends T> mapper`. However, this way the mapper would be totaly omited, which might not be the desired behaviuor.
2. Otherwise, you should pass into your SpecialList constructor a combination of the original supplier and new mapper like so:

```java
    return new SpecialList<R>(() -> {
        T originalValue = this.supplier.get();
        return mapper.apply(originalValue);
    };
```

Comment: did you read the existing answers before writing another one? your second suggestion is more or less what I had used for the method map() already in my answer. And the first one (as you noticed yourself) is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: My comment might seem harsh and narrow-minded, but I always find it a pity at SO, when a question gets many similar answers instead of people trying in a joint effort to improve the already existing ones. But I'm aware that this of course has to do with the way SO gives credits, so please don't feel offended.